# VBA to set Value of a Cells as a HyperLink - MS Project to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project where I am exporting all Task from MS Project to an Excel Sheet (The MS Project Excel export is bad for notes)

I have the code working perfect to export the information. The issue here is that I want to reformat a cell within a Loop as a Hyperlink to a sharepoint link

The following code exports all values

```
 Set mySheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
 Dim myTask As Task


For Each myTask In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not myTask Is Nothing Then
            
            With myTask
                If .Active Then                    
                   
                    currentLine = currentLine + 1    
                    
                    Set excelrange = mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 1)
                    excelrange.Value = .ID 'myTask.UniqueID
                    
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 2).Value = "'" + .OutlineNumber
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 3).Value = AutoIndent(.OutlineLevel) + .Name
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 4).Value = .StartText
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 5).Value = .FinishText
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 6).Value = .Notes
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 7).Value = .ResourceNames
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 8).Value = .WBSPredecessors
                    mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 9).Value = .Text2
mysheet.HyperLinks.Add Anchor:=mySheet.Cells(currentline, 10), Address:=.Text2, TextToDisplay:= "Checklist"
                    
                    myBold = False
                    myColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    If .OutlineChildren.Count > 0 Then
                        myBold = True
                        myColor = RGB(255, 255, 153)
                    End If
                    
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 1), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 2), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 3), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 4), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 5), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 6), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 7), myBold, myColor)
                    Call myMainFormat(mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 8), myBold, myColor)   
 
                Else
                End If
            End With
```

What I would like is Cells(currentLine, 9) to be a hyperlink.

I tried

```
mySheet.HyperLink.Add Anchor:=Cells(currentLine, 9), Address:=.Text2, TextToDisplay:="Checklist",
```

However I get an 424 error on the Anchor:=Cells(currentLine, 9).
If I can get some guidance on solving this would be great.

Would also be handy if it check for text in this field, as there is not always text as well.

Thanks

Comment: `mySheet.HyperLink.Add Anchor:=mySheet.Cells(currentLine, 9), Address:=.Text2, TextToDisplay:="Checklist", `  Without a worksheet qualifier, `Cells()` refers to whatever is the ActiveSheet (which may not be the same as `mySheet`)

Comment: If you're running this in MSProject, it also has no idea what `Cells()` refers to, since that's an Excel concept...

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks while being run from MS Project, the suggestion you provided gives a 438 error.

Comment: I haven't memorized all of the error numbers, so what's the *text* of the error message?   `mySheet.HyperLinks.Add` - missed that typo....

Comment: VBA Object Doesn't support this property or Method Error

Comment: Not fixed by correcting the `HyperLink` >> `HyperLinks` ?

Comment: Nope, back to a 424 "Object Required" error

Comment: Do you have a reference added in MSProject to the Excel object model?

Comment: Yes I do, hence the rest of the code working

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly where you added the hyperlink line?

Comment: Added, please note I am using (currentLine, 10) for testing and debuging.

Comment: Have you tried adding fixed values for the Address and TextToDisplay parameters (like my example below)?  If that doesn't work I can't guess why not...

Comment: Yes I have, part of my testing

Comment: Can you get something like my example working from Project?  i.e. the simplest possible test of creating a link...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me from Word (I don't have MS project for testing).
I don't have an Excel reference added - using late binding.

```
Sub AddLink()
    
    Dim xl As Object, ws As Object
    
    'connect to open excel
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    'refer to an existing worksheet
    Set ws = xl.workbooks("202310 VBA.xlsb").worksheets("Data")
    
    'add a hyperlink
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(5, "A"), _
                      Address:="https://google.com", _
                      TextToDisplay:="Google"

End Sub
```

"Would also be handy if it check for text in this field" - you can do that by wrapping the hyperlink code in `If Len(.Text2) > 0 Then ... End If`

Comment: Thanks however the following the add a hyperlink is the same as in the code I have above which is not working.